# how do i open the developer menu of react-native

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, expo

I am trying to open it using

> npm run web
> but it doesn't work instead it gives this error

```
some-random-app@1.0.0 web
> expo start --web

Starting project at C:\Users\surya\OneDrive\Desktop\react-native\some-random-app
Starting Metro Bundler
Starting Webpack on port 19006 in development mode.
‼ ｢wds｣: transportMode is an experimental option, meaning its usage could potentially change without warning
node:internal/crypto/hash:71
  this[kHandle] = new _Hash(algorithm, xofLen);
                  ^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:140:10)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\surya\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:135:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (C:\Users\surya\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:417:16)
    at handleParseError (C:\Users\surya\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:471:10)
    at C:\Users\surya\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:503:5
    at C:\Users\surya\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:358:12
    at C:\Users\surya\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:373:3
    at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\Users\surya\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
    at Array.<anonymous> (C:\Users\surya\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:205:4)
    at Storage.finished (C:\Users\surya\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:55:16)
    at C:\Users\surya\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:91:9
    at C:\Users\surya\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:123:16
    at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (node:internal/fs/read_file_context:68:3) {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}

Node.js v19.3.0
```

how do i overcome this

i just want to open the developer menu of react

Comment: Can you try force updating openSSL? this may resolve your issue. Run this command npm install --global --force-latest openssl

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work, i appreciate the efforts tough